# Insert cell in collection view, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a collection view made with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout, with different sections and cells.

I fetch some data through my API and then I insert this data in my dataSource like this:

```
if let index = self.dataSource.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == "Cell with loader" }) {
    self.dataSource.remove(at: index)
    if !data.isEmpty {
        self.dataSource.insert(data, at: index)
        self.reloadCollectionViewSection?(.recapCards, .insertAndRemove)
    } else {
        self.reloadCollectionViewSection?(.recapCards, .remove)
    }
}
```

This is my method to reload data in sections:

```
viewModel.reloadCollectionViewSection = { [weak self] section, action in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    switch action {
    case .remove:
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: section.rawValue)
            self.collectionView.deleteSections(indexSet)
        }, completion: nil)
    case .insert:
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: section.rawValue)
            self.collectionView.insertSections(indexSet)
        }, completion: nil)
    case .insertAndRemove:
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: section.rawValue)
            self.collectionView.deleteSections(indexSet)
            self.collectionView.insertSections(indexSet)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

---

My question is: what if an API finish before another and I insert a section at an index that doesn't exist? I need that those section are ordered (that's the main reason of my insert), but is there a safer approach? I don't know if section 3 is added or not (it depends from my api), so how can I add ordered sections maximising my performance?

I can sort the section when everything is done, but I don't like this approach. How can I insert, remove and update section in the safest way?

Comment: Have you tried looking at Diffable Data? It's the modern way of delivering data to collectionviews for exactly the reasons you describe.

Comment: Yes I did! but unfortunately diffable data source doesn't fit my case, cause I need to perform animation with index etc ...